# Won't go back to Windows!

Tags: windows-7

I installed Ubuntu on my C drive. I can't get back to Windows I tried almost everything! If you can help please answer. Did I delete my Windows 7? Please respond.

Comment: it depends what you selected when installation started. So what have you selected ?

Comment: More information needed. Current disc lay-out? what does `sudo fdisk -l` show? What did you choose when partitioning the disc? And you -did- make a backup of your important personal files, didn't you?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, boot up a Windows 7 disc.

Select your keyboard options.

[image: Keyboard Option]

Now, click next. Then click 'Repair your Computer...'

[image: Repair your computer]

Now select 'Command Prompt'.

[image: Section]

Now, type `cd\`, then enter. Then type `fdisk`, then enter. If it says 'Do you want to continue?' press 'Y', and then enter.

[image: fdisk]

As you can see, you can create partitions. Create one that's DOS-based (A primary one.)
[image: DOS]

Then, delete the Linux-based one.

**Installing Windows 7**

Now, this is quite easy. Boot off the Windows 7 disc.

Set the keyboard settings.

Then, click 'Install Now.'

At the installation type screen, click 'Custom'.

[image: Install]

Now, click the only option.

[image: Disk option]

Now, type your PC name, and user account.

[image: User Account]

Follow the steps and you will have Windows in no time!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look into your root directory `/`. Are there any Windows specific files?

- You can look it up in Nautilus.
- or per console: type `cd /` followed by `ls` to list files.

If there are folders like *Windows*, *Program Files*, you have NOT deleted your windows installation. If you just want to access your old files, it will be easy. If you want to use your Windows again, it will be hard.

**Access Files:**

- Just copy your files with Nautilus to an USB-Stick or an external Hard Drive. Eventually you'll have to start Nautilus with privileged rights (type in console `sudo nautilus`).

**Reuse Windows:**

- Have a look at [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/).

Comment: I said about recovering windows first XD

Comment: You didn't write it first. You just posted it first ;-)

Comment: True, true! :-D